# trying to change from query_post to WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I am running a theme which is using `query_post` now I am trying to change it to `WP_Query`. However I am always getting a blank empty page with just the header.
This is my query:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```

I am than calling a loop file with `get_template_part( 'loop', 'coupon' );`
Within this I have `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`.

I changed this to WP_Query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and to `if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();`

but I am so stuck...

Comment: Do you also have an `endwhile;`? Can you post the entire code?

Comment: Yes I do habe `endwhile;` and added `wp_reset_postdata(); ` this is the original `loop` file https://pastebin.com/588vHskN

Comment: I don't see `WP_Query` in that link. Can you post the code you are using and that is causing the error?

Comment: I think I found the problem, will test a little and if there is still a problem get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is caused by variable scope...

Everything is fine, when you use global `$wp_query`, because it is a global variable and functions like `have_posts` and `the_post` are aware of that, so you can use them in template parts.

On the other hand, you define your custom query. Then you get template part and you want to use that variable inside that template - but this variable is not accessible in there because it is not a global variable.

That's why your way of dividing code into parts is not so common. It would be much better, easier to maintain and more secure, if you'd write it like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    $query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'coupon' );  // or get_template_part( 'content', 'coupon' );
endwhile;
```

And in `loop-coupon.php` should be only the content of single post.

This way you can use the same template part for different loops, so it is easier to re-use.

Comment: Hi I use your code, however it looks like the side I trying to load but is stuck in the loop. This is the newest file: https://pastebin.com/QVTaqDhY and this is the loop file: https://pastebin.com/jy6SUwPM

Comment: I think I found the problem, will test a little and if there is still a problem get back to you.